# How can I declare OR-Dependency in smart.json for Meteorite?

Tags: meteorite

You define the packages your package is dependent on in the smart.json for example like this:

`{
    [...],
    "packages": {
        "package1": {},
        "package2": {}
    }
}`

This means my package is dependent on package1 AND package2. Is it possible to declare my package dependent on package1 OR package2?

Answer (score 0):

No, I would be highly suprised if there were such a way to include packages. If you really want to be dependent on one of two packages you are going to have to implement that in your package code (you would be dependant on both packages and your logic would have to choose which package to use).

The next best thing I can think of is editing the package.js file which allows you to create a weak dependency:

> It is possible to create weak dependencies between packages. If
>   package A has a weak dependency on package B, it means that including
>   A in an app does not force B to be included too — but, if B is
>   included, say by the app developer or by another package, then B will
>   load before A. You can use this to make packages that optionally
>   integrate with or enhance other packages if those packages are
>   present. To create a weak dependency, pass {weak: true} as the third
>   argument to api.use. When you weakly depend on a package you don't see
>   its exports. You can detect if the possibly-present weakly-depended-on
>   package is there by seeing if Package.foo exists, and get its exports
>   from the same place.

Maybe there is an alternative soulution, care to elaborate why you want your package dependecies to be like this?

Comment: It's quite an exotic feature-wish. And it's not my own packages depending on. To be concrete, I'm using "livestamp" wich is dependent on "moment". I'm using "moment-with-langs" wich is enough. Right now I have moment and moment-with-langs added which seems one package too much for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with [one of packages](https://github.com/pahans/reactive-modal/) I have developed. what I did was simply NOT indicating any dependancy in the smart.json file and let the user decide which package he/she wants to use, and I have mentioned it clearly on package's getting started guide.
in my case it is a bootstrap3 package I wanted